# How can I put a unary minus sign after a column separator?

Tags: math-mode

I am using the `aligned` environment in order to have a sequence of left-aligned equations.

In this latex code:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
& a = b \\
& -c = d
\end{aligned}
\]
```

There is some space between the minus sign and the "c" even though I want it to be a unary minus.

How can I make this minus sign that comes after an `&` be a unary minus?

Ideally I would like to have a way to do this that works with KaTeX, since that is what I'm using to render math (although this issue appears to happen with pdflatex too.)

Comment: I often help myself with pictures for my inadequacy in English language. In my case, an image could help me solve your problem.

Comment: `&{-c}` should do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply encase the `-` symbol in curly braces. Doing so changes the symbol's math status from `bin` to `ord` (ordinary).

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
& a = b \\
& {-}c = d
\end{aligned}
\]
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
& a = b \\
& -c = d\\
& {-}c = d
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have not understood the question :-( my congratulations.